# Reverse coordinates in PostgreSQL polygon column

Tags: postgresql, polygon

I have a PostgreSQL 11 table containing a POLYGON column, with currently about 100 rows, and each polygon with between 3 and about 15 corner points. It now turns out that I mistakenly created my data with reversed X and Y coordinates. Therefore I now would like to swap the coordinates to rectify this mistake.

Minimal working example:

```
CREATE TABLE geom_example (shape POLYGON);
INSERT INTO geom_example (shape) VALUES ('(1, 2), (5, 2), (1, 3)');
```

I would like to reverse the coordinates so that

```
(1, 2), (5, 2), (1, 3)
```

becomes:

```
(2, 1), (2, 5), (3, 1)
```

for all the rows of the table.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ST_SwapOrdinates`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/ST_SwapOrdinates.html), which is made just for that:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
          ST_SwapOrdinates(
             'POLYGON((1 2,5 2,1 3,1 2))'::geometry,
             'xy'
          )
       );

         st_astext          
════════════════════════════
 POLYGON((2 1,2 5,3 1,2 1))
(1 row)
```